# Como tratar uma imagem de alta resolução

Tags: android, compressão-de-imagem

Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar enviar uma imagem de alta resolução para um WS.

Capturo a imagem,pego o caminho dela e envio como parâmentro para outra activity no qual envia para o WS.

Antes de enviar a imagem para o WS faço um tratamento nela devido seu tamanho, celulares com resolução acima de 8mp já da estouro de memória.

Fiz alguns ajustes no meu código porém ainda esta dando crash de memória.

Chamada do método:

```
private void TakeFoto(View v)
{
    try{
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(getApplicationContext()))); 
          startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} 

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
                try {
                final File file = getTempFile(this);
                Bitmap captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                Uri imagemSelecionada = getImageUri(getBaseContext(),captureBmp);
                String[] colunas = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imagemSelecionada,colunas, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int indexColuna = cursor.getColumnIndex(colunas[0]);
                String pathImg = cursor.getString(indexColuna);
                cursor.close();
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("imagem", pathImg);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, TelaDadosUpload.class);
                intent.putExtras(params);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
          String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
          return Uri.parse(path);
        }


private File getTempFile(Context context){
          //it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
          final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
          if(!path.exists()){
            path.mkdir();
          }
          return new File(path, "image.tmp");
        }
```

Metodo de upload para o WS:

```
public void upload(String fileUri)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/WS/upload.php");

        String fileName = fileUri;
        try{
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,(int)(bm.getWidth()*1.0), (int)(bm.getHeight()*1.0), true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, output); //bm is the bitmap object   
            byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray();

            try{
                String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> valores = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",base64Image));
                valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipodoc",ClasseUsuario.spinner));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valores));
                HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            }

            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 

            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Nesse ponto acontece o erro:
Pela mensagem do log parece que o problema esta no decodeFile da classe BitmapFactory
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O log:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar este problema?
Obrigado.

Comment: Tem como colocar o erro que está sendo apresentado?

Comment: Claro Tony, falha minha. Vou editar meu tópico com o momento do erro.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente utilizar o atributo `android:largeHeap="true"` na tag `<application ...` do seu Manifest. Isso incrementa um pouco de memória a sua aplicação e já utilizei para sanar um problema de estouro de memória parecido com o seu. Link para a [Documentação do Android sobre o LargeHeap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica LeoSantana, esta complicado resolver este problema do estouro de memória.